# Cosmos SQL API: filter based an array entry

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Given the json

```
{
    "fileIds": [
        "171824c7-1485-4b35-9418-2b40aea8fa48",
        "b158e946-621f-431e-926c-57577e3e0b6b"
    ],
    "eventType": 8,
    "description": "File deleted from original storage account",
    "registerTimeUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "customerId": "c7b00078-8fd7-49ad-989a-2fabcb767f6e",
    "applicationId": "266c6ca3-e77c-4233-b780-b8dd69aa7349"
    ...
```

}

I need to check if an entry exists based on a given applicationId, eventType and fileId and I do not know how to write the query based on fileId to check its existence in the array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Root r where 
    r.applicationId = '266c6ca3-e77c-4233-b780-b8dd69aa7349' and 
    r.eventType = 8 and 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.fileIds, '171824c7-1485-4b35-9418-2b40aea8fa48')
```

To search for an item in an array, you will need to use [`ARRAY_CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) function.